# How to remove duplicates options from the datalist in HTML using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on a search box where  I used Flask, MySQL and Ajax to get the search suggestion while writing any query.
I am getting response from the ajax call back when I start writing in the search box and I am appending new option which generate lot's of duplicates option because suggestion can be similar in another response so I want to delete that.

Here is the duplicate option problem

(In the Right Side You Can see the duplicates option showing in console) -

[image]

Here is my Ajax -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#searchbox").on("input", function(e){
            searchtext = $("#searchbox").val();
            
            $.ajax({
                method:"post",
                url:"/searchengine",
            
                data:{text:searchtext},
                success:function(res){
                
                    $.each(res,function(index,value){
                         options =  "<option value="+value.address+">";
                            console.log(options)
                    });
                    $('#results').append(options);
             
                                }
            })

        
                        
            
        });
    })
</script>
```

Can you please tell me how can I delete these duplicate values from datalist in HTML
THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: You are overwriting `options` at every loop. You are doing `options="a"` then `options="b"` then `option="c"` etc. No matter how many loops there are, after the loop, the value of `options` will always be the last one (in this case, "Dhar").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you not just add new values, but form new list of options and replace old one with it. So, instead of `$('#results').append(options)` you go with `$('#results').empty().append(options)`. This way you will have only new options and no duplicates (unless there is some in your data).